# Trying to bring localhost php shopping cart to godaddy and having problems

Tags: php, mysql, database

First of all I am new to php sysql and databases.  I do know a little c++ so this helps with php.  I do not really understand databases though so my question is:.....

This is my code:

```
<?php


echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.'lensClensProducts/views/layouts/'.$controller.'.php';


// Includes our database functions
include('db_functions.php');

// includes our cart functions
include('cart_fns.php');

session_start();

 // set up default cart values
 if(!isset($_SESSION['cart']))
 {
     $_SESSION['cart']      =   array();    
     $_SESSION['total_items']   =   0;
     $_SESSION['total_price']   =      '0.00';
 }

// Defaults to index view unless user requests different view
$view = empty($_GET['view']) ? 'index' : $_GET['view'];

// Used for layout
$controller = 'shop';

 // checks which view is requested by user.
 switch ($view) {

   case "index":

         $products = find_products();

   break;

   case "add_to_cart":
         $id = $_GET['id'];
         $add_item = add_to_cart($id);
         $_SESSION['total_items'] = total_items($_SESSION['cart']);
         $_SESSION['total_price'] = total_price($_SESSION['cart']);
         header('Location: index.php');
   break;   

   case "update_cart":
         update_cart();
         $_SESSION['total_items'] = total_items($_SESSION['cart']);
         $_SESSION['total_price'] = total_price($_SESSION['cart']);
         header('Location: index.php?view=checkout'); 
   break;        

   case "checkout":

       if ( 0    < $_SESSION['total_price'] && $_SESSION['total_price'] <= 100  )
       {
           $shipping = 11.95;
       }

       if ( 100  < $_SESSION['total_price'] && $_SESSION['total_price'] <= 250  )
       {
           $shipping = 18.50;
       }

       if ( 250  < $_SESSION['total_price'] && $_SESSION['total_price'] <= 500  )
       {
           $shipping = 25.50;
       }

       if ( 500  < $_SESSION['total_price'] && $_SESSION['total_price'] <= 1000 )
       {
           $shipping = 36.00;
       }

       if ( 1000 < $_SESSION['total_price'] && $_SESSION['total_price'] <= 2500 )
       {
           $shipping = 64.50;
       }

       else if ( 2500 < $_SESSION['total_price'] )
       {
           $shipping = 250.00;
       }

   break;        

 }

// includes layout for controller
include( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.'lensClensProducts/views/layouts/'.$controller.'.php' );

?>
```

I am having a problem with the last line the include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.'gamelist/views/layouts/'.$controller.'.php' );

PS there is also an echo on line 16 of this code

one in particular the ['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] I guess that is a global variable.

Im the local host this show up and works fine, in go daddy this does not do anything but give me an error

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/27/6235127/html/gamelist/index.php:4) in /home/content/27/6235127/html/gamelist/index.php on line 16

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/content/27/6235127/html/gamelist/index.php:4) in /home/content/27/6235127/html/gamelist/index.php on line 16
/gamelist/views/layouts/index.php

I quess this has something to do with the server name I used the server name of lensclens3.db.6235127.hostedresource.com and that did not work.

I know this server name above works as it is used (and working) on another page of this shopping cart.

Is there another server name I should be using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Headers already sent by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)

Answer (score 0):

Pages are sent from a server in a certain order, first headers, and then the page content. You can use various functions in PHP to set or modify the headers, but the server will automatically compose some defaults if you don't make your own.

A command like echo will send page content, information you can actually see/read on the page.

A command such as session_start sends headers, invisible information passed to the browser. In the case of session_start, the information is tracking information, a lot like a cookie.

By using an echo command, you tell the server to start serving content, and it has to send headers. If you use session_start after the headers are already sent, PHP throws a warning to say "I can't use this command because headers were already sent and I started serving the content."